# Lowering my range

Tags: technique, learning, exercises, health, vocal-range

I have improved my upper range a great deal since I started singing.  When I started singing 7 years ago, I had an F above middle C, now I'm up to a B flat.  My lower range, however, has only budged a half step, from F below the bass staff, to E.  However, I have just been cast in a role that requires E flat.  Any advice?  Even if it's not specifically singing advice, diet, exercise, whatever I need to do to hit the note...I'll try.

P.S. If I can't hit it two weeks before the show, they said I have to transpose it up an octave, which is not nearly as impressive sounding, and not what the composer intended.

Comment: What's the piece? How often does Eb feature? What accompaniment is used? Could you sing a harmony to the Eb? Could it be transposed? Could you 'speak' the word Eb lands on?

Comment: It's Move Toward the Darkness from The Addams Family. The accompaniment will be a live orchestra. The only other note they will let me sing is the E flat an octave up. And they're not going to transpose it. It's the last thing I sing in the show so it would be pretty anticlimactic to speak it. That would just not fit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest exercises with 'aah', 'yaah' and 'aeh' sounds. Go down from c until the note you can sing like five steps each time chromatically... (C B Bb A Ab brethe and B Bb A Ab G breathe....)